# Error inflating class android.widget.GridLayout app crash

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

When I try to run my app in Android Studio emulator everything works fine, but when I try to run it on my phone (LG G4) the app crashes and the error on the logs is:

> Error inflating class android.widget.GridLayout

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="360dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/board"
            android:columnCount="3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:rowCount="3">
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="0"
                app:layout_column="0"
                app:layout_row="0" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="1"
                app:layout_column="1"
                app:layout_row="0" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="2"
                app:layout_column="2"
                app:layout_row="0" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="3"
                app:layout_column="0"
                app:layout_row="1" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="4"
                app:layout_column="1"
                app:layout_row="1" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="5"
                app:layout_column="2"
                app:layout_row="1" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="6"
                app:layout_column="0"
                app:layout_row="2" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="7"
                app:layout_column="1"
                app:layout_row="2" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="8"
                app:layout_column="2"
                app:layout_row="2" />
        </GridLayout>
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/playAgainLayout"
            android:layout_width="189dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#46d65e"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/gridLayout"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.011"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/winnerMessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/playAgainButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:onClick="playAgain"
                android:text="Play Again" />
        </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // 0 = yellow, 1 = red;
    int activePlayer = 0;

    // 2 means unplayed
    int [] gameState= {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};

    int [] [] winningPositions = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {0,4,8}, {2,4,6}};

    public void dropIn (View view){

        ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;

        System.out.println(counter.getTag().toString());

        int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());

        if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2) {

            gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;

            counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);

            if (activePlayer == 0) {
                counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                activePlayer = 1;
            } else {
                counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                activePlayer = 0;
            }

            counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).rotation(360f).setDuration(500);

            for (int [] winningPosition : winningPositions){
                if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
                        gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                        gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2){

                    //Someone has won

                    String winner = "Red";

                    if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0){

                        winner = "Yellow";
                    }



                    TextView winnerMeassage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);
                    winnerMeassage.setText(winner + " has won!");

                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);

                    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }

        }

    }

    public void playAgain (View view){

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);

        layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        // 0 = yellow, 1 = red;
        activePlayer = 0;

        // 2 means unplayed
        for (int i = 0 ; i < gameState.length ; i++){
            gameState[i] = 2;
        }

        // setting all the images source to nothing


        GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);


        for(int i = 0 ; i<gridLayout.getChildCount() ; i++){

            ((ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I don't think the code will help but it is here if you want to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your drawable folder. Sometimes when your images are in v24 drawable folder this error happens move your images to drawable folder.

Comment: there is only one drawable folder and the images are in it

Comment: @camelboy... There is only one drawable folder when you check them right from Android-Studio... You've to go to that location from your file-explorer... In most of the case path is: *`C://Users/[userName]/AndroidStudioProjects/[projectName]/app/src/main/res/`*, check out there

Comment: Right Click on drawable on android studio and choose Show In Explorer and you will see drawable-v24 copy your images to drawable folder.

Comment: thank you very much it worked.

I don't know why Android Studio has so many problems I hope they fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Try withe support library version.

add via gradle 
`implementation com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1`

replace `<GridLayout>` with `<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>`

Also change the import to support library

Comment: I did what you said I ended up with the error:

Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout

Comment: same problem, I don't know what to do

Comment: maybe I didn't add the library correctly can you explain to me how to do it step by step, sorry I am new to Android Studio.